# Peculiar Dropdown response on only one PC

Tags: ms-access, dropdown

I have a MS Access program that has been running and evolving over the last 5 years or more and one PC has a unique problem.

On one form there is a dropdown used to look up an address. As they type in the address the dropdown progressively refines the list. E.g. if they type in 6, it will list all entries starting with 6, if they then type 5, i.e. 65, the dropdown displays entries starting with 65, etc. It works perfectly on every machine with every number/character sequence - except one machine and only with the number 7.

If, on this one machine, they type in 7, it displays the first entry, namely "700 St Michael" and the cursor moves to the end of the field instead of allowing them to enter the next number in the search. I've tried copying a new version of the FE from my machine where it works normally (it's linked to a common BE on a server) but it still does the same thing - but only on that machine.

Can anyone suggest where I should look for a fix?

Rob

Comment: Look at: **File > Options > Client Settings > Behavior Entering Field** for Access on that computer. Although why only number 7 would cause this is the real mystery. Question not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that setting. If it's not appropriate for SO, do you know of any forum that it would apply to? Not sure where to go with this strange problem?

Comment: There are many forums that focus on Access. AccessForums.net is one.

Comment: I once had a machine that would not behave same as others. Ended up trading with another employee that did not need to run the database.

Comment: Maybe their keyboard is broken? (only half-kidding)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will try swapping the keyboard - maybe you're right - and if that doesn't work I will try  AccessForums.net. Appreciate your help